# Windows Phone - How to refresh an access token?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, owin, access-token

I have created a Web Api using the Visual Studio 2013 Web Api template. It works perfectly providing an access token and a refresh token as well. (Default behavior)

But I have got a question: How to refresh the access code for a Windows Phone application? Do I have to use a timer to check the expiration date and make a new post request?

I'm so lost that I'm not able to write my own question :)

What I want to do is to store the refresh token and a simple way to get a new access code.

I really appreciate a sample or a code. Just to give me an idea how it works.

Thanks

Comment: Does your token contain a timestamp or expirydate? In that case, you could have a TokenExpired(token); call before your interaction with the API and if your token's validity has ellapsed, request a refresh token. No need to have a background task or a timer. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you Chris. So what I've to do is to check whether or not a refresh token is valid right? If not, I'll make a new post request to obtain a new access code (and I'll receive a new refresh token as well). But I'll need the user credentials again because the Token route requires the username and the password in the body request. I do not want to store the username and password. As I said, I'm lost. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi Bruno, you said that your API can issue access and refresh tokens. Do you require credentials for the refresh token? If that's the case, I would use the Credential Locker to store the username and password in order to be able to reuse them when requesting the token the second time. Optionally, you could delete the entry from the locker upon closing down the app

Comment: That´s work for me, I'll do it. Thanks Chis.